# NodeJS: Dynamic form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How do I create a dynamic form with NodeJS, Express and Mongoose?

Right now my contents are hardcoded for the sake of the question.

This is how my page creation looks like:

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
    var page;
    var b = req.body;

    page = new Page({
        title: b.title,
        url: '/' + Func.stringToUrlSlug(b.title) + '/',
        headline: b.headline,

        contents: [{
                body: b.content1_body,
                class: 'CLASS1'
            },{
                body: b.content2_body,
                class: 'CLASS2'
            },{
                body: b.content3_body,
                class: 'CLASS3'
            }],

        border: b.border,
        target: b.target,
        hidden: b.hidden,
        externUrl: b.externUrl,
        order: 700
    });

    page.save(function(err, page) {
        if (!err)
            res.send(page);
        else
            res.send(err);
    });
});
```

And my Jade frontend creation:

```
....
div
    label Content
    textarea(name='content1_body')

div
    label Content
    textarea(name='content2_body')

div
    label Content
    textarea(name='content3_body')
....
```

And my mongoose schema contents are of Array type.

My question here is: How can I have these documents to being dynamic in my route depending on how many extra content fields I add?

Do I need to push these extra fields inside my page array somehow?

Say if something is unclear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after aaaaa lot of trying I solved it myself.

I ended up creating my form elements that should be dynamic this way:

```
        div
            label Class
            input(name='content[1][class]')

            label Content
            textarea(name='content[1][body]')

        div
            label Class
            input(name='content[2][class]')

            label Content
            textarea(name='content[2][body]')
....
```

That way I could reach the content fields, wether it was the class or the body field. And I ended up pushing these into my page array:

```
b.content.forEach(function(item) {
    page.contents.push({ class: item.class, body: item.body });
});
```

I end up adding more form fields with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches how to implement "dynamic forms". The easiest would be using the  single page application features that you do not load the page at all when you move between the forms. The result could be stored in document.localStorage and when the user has finished send the results to server.

When you do not use the client side possibilities, you have to store the each form results in temporary database "table/document", also you have to keep track on what form the user is. When user reaches end, insert all the data from previous steps to table/document.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the extended parsing of the [Express body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

```
var app = express();
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Express will use the [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#readme) library. This library has automated parsing for converting query parameters to array or objects.

Example (source: qs docs)

```
var withIndexes = qs.parse('a[1]=c&a[0]=b');
assert.deepEqual(withIndexes, { a: ['b', 'c'] });
```

After correctly parsing your inputs, it's a matter of sending this info to mongoose.